# Cloudify architecture

Tags: cloudify

I am trying to setup cloudify in an OpenStack installation using [this offline guide](http://getcloudify.org/downloads/workingofflinewithcloudify3.4-latest.pdf).

This guide does not specify much about cloud platform so I have assumed it can be used on OpenStack environment. I am using simple manager blueprint YAML file for bootstrapping .

I have the following questions:

1. Can I use fabric 1.4.2 with cloudify 3.4.1 ?
2. If not, I am unable to find `wagon-file` for `fabric 1.4.1.wgn` file
3. Architecture: Can I use CLI inside a network to bootstrap a manager within that network? And this network lies inside OpenStack environment. Can cloudify CLI machine, cloudify Manager and application reside within one network inside openstack? If so, how? Because we would like to test it inside one single network.

Answer (score 0):

(Full disclosure: I wrote the document you linked to.)

1. Yes you can.
2. You can find all Wagon files for all versions of the Fabric plugin here: https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-fabric-plugin/releases
3. Yes.